# How To Make Concrete Acid Stain For Floors

Tags: concrete, flooring, floor, staining, epoxy

Recently I completed my concrete floor done inside my house. But that doesn't look good all the way. I don't want to do tiling, Because i feel that costly. So I planned to do acid staining so that might gives glossy & good looks.

I was looking around for available Acid Stain in Bangladesh. But Unfortunately there's no available products at all! So I was thinking to made a own version of Acid Stain to use on my floors.

I need help on that how to make a Concrete Acid Stain. What formula needed and how to deal with it. I'm complete noobs on these things.

**NB:** We need the flooring to get as much cheaper way possible

Below I attached sample of my floor currently done.

[image: Current Floor]
[image: Current Floor Looks]

Comment: i think that you are wrong about using acid stain to make the floor glossy ... acid removes gloss from concrete

Comment: Floor paint? Some good products available but need good preparation.

Comment: In my limited experience, acid would give the floor a very dull look. When you see photos of beautiful acid-stained concrete, usually there is a sealer applied after the stain. It is the sealer that gives the glossy, wet look. Some sealers are expensive. I wonder if a floor wax could be a less costly substitute.

Comment: @GregHill Thank you so much for your advise & and all of you. 

I really Wish to improve my floor. appreciate any DIY Idea.